# animation in android & eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have about 200 pictures *(size = 600x480)* in an animation. I want to play the animation when I click, but, on my real Android phone, my app will close without displaying any error messages. Can I fix it? Does any solution exist?

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_0001" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_0002" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_0003" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_0004" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_0005" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_0006" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_0007" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_0008" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_0009" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00010" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00011" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00012" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00013" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00014" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00015" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00016" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00017" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00018" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00019" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00020" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00021" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00022" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00023" android:duration="22"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/an_00024" android:duration="22"/>
```

Comment: Are you saying that your animation works in your emulator when you click on it, but it doesn't work on your real android device?

Comment: yep . i use genymotion emulator my tablet is galaxy tab 7 plus

Comment: Please check again your logCat and post it, so we can see what's the problem.

Comment: this is the problem . on emulator its worked but not working on device . i think its caused by memory

Comment: Which API are you testing on your emulator, and which API are you using on your phone?

Comment: i tested on galaxy s3 and even s5 but still the same